# How to debug save_post actions in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, post

I have some custom post meta being generated and am ready to add to a post's meta. I know how to do this. However, `save_post` causes a redirection after POST data has been sent. This means I am redirected to the dashboard and lose access to my POST data - therefore I cannot debug easily.

Currently I am using something like:

```
add_action('save_post', 'something_process');

function something_process() {
   if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
       return;
   print_r($_POST);
}
```

Is there a way to *easily* debug this?

Comment: I'm doing: die(print_r($_POST))

Comment: @Tumas: Your solution seems handy for a **quick** debugging. You should have put it as an **answer** instead of having it as a comment.

Comment: @gmaggio my thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best approach for me has been to use a function to log the values to wp-content/debug.log, lifted from http://fuelyourcoding.com/simple-debugging-with-wordpress:

```
if(!function_exists('log_it')){
 function log_it( $message ) {
   if( WP_DEBUG === true ){
     if( is_array( $message ) || is_object( $message ) ){
       error_log( print_r( $message, true ) );
     } else {
       error_log( $message );
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Then use the function like this in your save_post hook:

```
log_it($_POST);
log_it('The value for ' . $custom_field . ' is ' . $_POST[$custom_field]);
```

Make sure that wp-content/debug.log is writable, and that you have debugging enabled in wp-config.php:

```
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
define( 'WP_DEBUG',         true );  // Turn debugging ON
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false ); // Turn forced display OFF
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG',     true );  // Turn logging to wp-content/debug.log ON
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false); // Disables revision functionality
```

Answer (score 5):

## Method 1:

```
if (isset($_POST)) die(print_r($_POST)); //answer by Tumas
```

## Method 2:

*create log file (**my_logs.txt**) in a folder, where you use this code:*

```
add_action('save_post', 'something_process',11,11);
function something_process() 
{
    print_r($_POST);
    $tmp = fopen(dirname(__file__).'/my_logs.txt', "a+"); fwrite($tmp,"\r\n\r\n".ob_get_contents());fclose($tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found so far is storing the `$_POST` in a session var for access later.

Answer (score 2):

First Approach:

```
die(print_r($post_id));
```

Second Approach:

```
var_dump($post_id);
```

Third Approach:

```
<?php
  echo <pre>{whatever you want to echo goes here}</pre>
?>
```

Or take any browser add-ons for console logging

may one of three help..Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

You could also save your debug messages in a WordPress option and show it as an admin message after the redirect.

```
// display all notices after saving post
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'show_admin_notices', 0 );

// your custom save_post aciton
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_save_post' );

function custom_save_post() {
    store_error_in_notices_option( 'my debug message' );
}

function store_error_in_notices_option( $m ) {
    if ( ! empty( $m ) ) {
        // store error notice in option array
        $notices = get_option( 'my_error_notices' );
        $notices[] = $m;
        update_option( 'my_error_notices', $notices );
    }
}

function show_admin_notices() {
    $notices = get_option( 'my_error_notices' );
    if ( empty( $notices ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // print all messages
    foreach ( $notices as $key => $m ) {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>' . $m . '</p></div>';
    }

    delete_option( 'my_error_notices' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this for a quick formatted output :

```
die( '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, true ) . '</pre>');
```